# how can i write multiple classes under a pom file

Tags: appium, pom.xml, appium-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp2pD.png)I want to add multiple classes in this pom file but which tag i should use and where, please can someone clarify this.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lnXm.png)

Comment: Class in pom.xml?? Why you need it?

Comment: hello @muzzamil , I want to different class files, like the below answer given, but in maven projects, what is the way to create those xml files!?

Comment: you meant test classes? classes where you have all test cases.

Comment: Yes, test classes @muzzamil

Comment: you are using junit or testng?

Comment: @muzzamil i'm using Maven and later added a testng library inside my maven project, please check the latest picture that I added

Comment: I have mentioned both ways to achieve the task. Please try it and let me know. you can follow blog/article for step by step for any way you prefer.

Comment: Please check  how you can post a good question. much needed https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml file is only for the dependencies and other maven settings, in order to control your test cases, create a new xml file, you can call it whateveryouwant.xml and it is in this file where you add settings to run your test cases. You can omit the parameters lines, my tcs are run like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MySuiteName">
    <test name="LG_V20">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="XXXXXX"></parameter>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="7"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port" value="4735"></parameter>
        <parameter name="port2" value="4736"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="TestCases.TC1"></class>
            <class name="TestCases.TC2"></class>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Hello, @adrian jimenez My project is Maven, and can you clarify exactly where should I create the xml file!

Comment: just select your project folder - right click and create new file, or just copy the existing pom.xml, rename it, delete the info. and paste my code, just change the needed info

Comment: please follow [this link](https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-test-using-testng/) to learn how to use testng in your project

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to execute `Testng` test cases using `Maven`

**Run Testng test cases directly Pom.xml without any Testng.xml (Not a recommended way as you can't avail many facilities of Textng.xml , specially controlling sequence etc)**

After creating testng test cases, Add `testng` dependency in `pom.xml` with `scope` as `test`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

[here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-maven-project-example/) is simple example or step by step guide (till step 5)

**Call Testng.xml for Pom.xml (Recommended way)**

After creating `Testng` test cases with `Testng.xml` we can call `testng.xml` using `maven surefire plugin` as mentioned below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

[Here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/maven-tutorials/how-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-testng-xml-using-maven) is step by step guide to do this.